# Neutralino pick file then readFile not working

Tags: javascript, neutralinojs

I select a file then read the file from the path returned by Neutralino.

```
 Neutralino.os.showOpenDialog('Select Image', {
        filters: [
            {name: 'Images', extensions: ['jpg', 'png']}
        ]
    }).then((__data) => {
        Neutralino.filesystem.readFile(__data[0]).then((__string) => {
            console.log('LOADED', __string);               
        }, (__error) => {console.log('ERR', __error)}).catch(__error => {console.log('Error', __error);});  
    });
```

In my case, when I select a file on the desktop for instance, the returned path `__data[0]` is

```
 C:/Users/Eric/Desktop/1595887262047.jpg
```

But then when I try to read the file, it silently fails. How do I load a file that is not a relative path?? I have no issue loading files with a relative path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`readFile`](https://neutralino.js.org/docs/api/filesystem#filesystemreadfilefilename) is for "*[reading] a **text file***". What you need is [`readBinaryFile`](https://neutralino.js.org/docs/api/filesystem#filesystemreadbinaryfilefilename).

Creating an image from binary in JavaScript is commonly done and well documented, here are some resources:

- [MDN - Using object urls to display images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_API/Using_files_from_web_applications#example_using_object_urls_to_display_images)
- [MDN - Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/type)
- [Random gist I found](https://gist.github.com/harun/825eb53168a3ed9ec4e51de3ecba0801)

One possible implementation using [SolidJS](https://www.solidjs.com/):

```
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import styles from "./App.module.css";

import { createSignal } from "solid-js";

function App() {
  const [img, setImg] = createSignal(logo);

  const handleFileChosen = (imgPath) => {
    Neutralino.filesystem
      .readBinaryFile(imgPath) // Read the image
      .then((imgData) => {
        // Get image extension e.g. png
        const ext = imgPath.split(".").pop();

        // Create a Blob using the returned ArrayBuffer data,
        // You need to specify what type of file it is
        const blob = new Blob([imgData], { type: `image/${ext}` });

        // Turn Blob into something we can use on <img> element
        const objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        setImg(objectUrl);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.warn(err);
      });
  };

  const handleFileDialog = () => {
    // Just in case it hasn't loaded yet
    Neutralino?.os
      .showOpenDialog("Select Image", {
        filters: [{ name: "Images", extensions: ["jpg", "png"] }],
      })
      .then((imgPaths) => {
        // Call with returned image path
        handleFileChosen(imgPaths[0]);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.warn(err);
      });
  };

  return (
    <div class={styles.App}>
      <header class={styles.header}>
        <img src={img()} class={styles.logo} alt="logo" />
        <!-- ... -->
        <button type="button" onClick={handleFileDialog}>
          Choose Image
        </button>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```